# createElement and componentDidMount in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a React application in a style that does not use `createClass`. This means that I'm using only `React.createElement()` function calls.

However, it is not clear to me how to get the `componentDidMount` type of callbacks for my element. What I want to achieve is that, after the elements are converted to DOM nodes, I'm getting such an event for each element/DOM node for which this event handler is set.

Example:

```
function f(){ alert("mounted!"); }
var p = React.createElement("div", { key: "msg", className: "message", componentDidMount: f }, ["hello world"]);
ReactDom.render(p, document.body.firstChild);
```

So, unfortunately, in the example above, `f` is never invoked.

Note that as part of the event, I need information about the DOM node (so I know which DOM node belongs to which element).

Answer (score 0):

so why not just use the onLoad handler?

```
React.createElement("div", { key: "msg", className: "message", onLoad: f }, ["hello world"]);
```

Comment: It seems that onLoad is only supported for images. See: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html

Comment: @peterp did you try it? I just used it with a div